# How to filter all but last returns using lidR?

Tags: r, lidar, filter, lidr

I am using the great `lidR` package and want to check all points classified as ground which are not the last returns.

How would I do that?

Something like this would this would be logic for me but its not working:

```r
ground <- filter_ground(las)

ground_nolast <- !filter_last(ground)
ground_nolast <- filter_poi(ground, ReturnNumber != -1L)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of "last" is ambiguous. The last returns include (1) the last in a sequence of many and (2) the first in a sequence of one. If you want to remove (1) + (2)

```r
ground_nolast <- filter_poi(ground, ReturnNumber != NumberOfReturn)
```

But you won't have a lot of point I guess because it removes all first returns. If you want only  (1)

```r
ground_nolast <- filter_poi(ground, ReturnNumber != NumberOfReturns | NumberOfReturns == 1L)
```

Of course for this to work `ReturnNumber` and `NumberOfReturns` must be properly populated and you should check your data with `las_check()` first.

Comment: Thanks for your ultra fast response! This is exactly what I was looking for.